# Possible overdraw: Root element paints background

Tags: android-layout

In my application, it appears this warning on the lints of Android:

> Possible overdraw: Root element paints background @drawable/main with
>   a theme that also paints a background (inferred theme is @android:style/Theme)

I wanna know how to correct this mistake, cause after checking and checking on internet, I just found that it is decreasing application speed cause it reload two times the background to put this source.

This is the source of my layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="@string/alta1"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/alta2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/continuaralta"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@drawable/boton"
    android:text="@string/continuar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/saliralta"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/continuaralta"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/continuaralta"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/continuaralta"
    android:background="@drawable/boton"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/salir" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neil Sainsbury, at http://www.earthtoneil.com/, says that Romain Guy has addressed the underlying issue at http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/window-backgrounds-ui-speed.html. See Neil's blog and search for your error message. Then, go to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html to learn how to apply background themes to the app as a whole and to individual activities.

This approach will at least cause the error message to no longer appear. Hitting the two-arrows icon to refresh the warnings in the lint window after making the fix was necessary in my case.

Comment: I don't understand what you did to fix this, you added `<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>` to your theme? Cause I tried that and I still see the warning.

Comment: As I understood, it doesn't fix the warning. But if you create a style item for your background and then set this style to your view, it will fix it. But I think, it just workaround. You can just ignore this warning with the same result.