# Accessibility Missing contentDescription attribute on image how to remove this warning?

Tags: android

Accessibility] Missing contentDescription attribute on image

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:background="#ff3333"
            android:src="@drawable/arrows" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730673/missing-contentdescription-attribute-on-image-in-xml

Answer (score 28):

In Eclipse

> Window->prefrences->Android->Lint Error Checking->Issues->
>   Accessibility->Content Decription->Severty select Ignore.

**OR**

add `android:contentDescription` in ImageView.

- [See here For More About Lint Error Checking](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/)

Comment: by ignorng descritption nw i m getng ths warning 
Possible overdraw: Root element paints background @drawable/temperature with a theme that also paints a 
 background (inferred theme is @android:style/Theme)...
on xml widget... android:background="@drawable/temperature">

Answer (score 4):

try by adding `android:contentDescription` for ImageView

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:background="#ff3333"
            android:src="@drawable/arrows" />
```

for more info see

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/04/accessibility-are-you-serving-all-your.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html#test

[Android Lint contentDescription warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500544/android-lint-contentdescription-warning)

Comment: by ignorng descritption nw i m getng ths warning Possible overdraw: Root element paints background @drawable/temperature with a theme that also paints a background (inferred theme is @android:style/Theme)... on xml widget... android:background="@drawable/temperature">

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195762/possible-overdraw-root-element-paints-background

Answer (score 3):

Type in ImageView

```
android:contentDescription="TODO"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this:

```
android:contentDescription="@string/description"
```

then go to yours **Strings.xml** and add this:

```
<string name="description"> YOUR_DESCRIPTION_HERE </string>
```