# Missing contentDescription attribute on image how to remove this warning?

Tags: android

Accessibility Missing contentDescription attribute on image

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="34dp"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:background="#ff3333"
    android:src="@drawable/arrows" />
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304847/accessibility-missing-contentdescription-attribute-on-image-how-to-remove-this-w

Answer (score 3):

You can use  the layout editor's `tools` or set the `android:contentDescription` to `null`.

Here's an example:

```
// You don't need a FrameLayout, 
// tell the layout editor what to "ignore" in your layout's parent

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:background="#ff3333"
        android:src="@drawable/arrows" />

</FrameLayout>
```

---

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="34dp"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:background="#ff3333"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/arrows" />
```

But even better you should consider adding a short `String` to accurately describe what the `ImageView` is for.

[From the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3acontentDescription):

> Defines text that briefly describes content of the view. This property
>   is used primarily for accessibility. Since some views do not have
>   textual representation this attribute can be used for providing such.
>
> Must be a string value, using '\;' to escape characters such as '\n'
>   or '\uxxxx' for a unicode character.

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in your xml imageView and it should go away.

```
 android:contentDescription:"@string/desc"
```